# Linq запрос к базе и получение пустых данных

Tags: c#, linq

Делаю запрос такого вида

```
    FenixContactsEntities db = new FenixContactsEntities();
    var request = from a in db.Contacts
    join com in db.Companies on a.CompanyID equals com.CompanyID into ljoin1
    from com in ljoin1.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
        {
          Surname = a.Surname,
          Name = a.Name,
          Middlename = a.Middlename != null ? a.Middlename : "Пусто",
          CompanyName = com.CompanyName != null ? com.CompanyName : "Пусто"
        };
return Json(request.ToList(),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Но почему то если у кого-то в базе отсутствует отчество или не указана компания, мне выдается вместо человека null причем по всем полям.
Ответ, который я забираю

```
[{"Surname":"Федоров","Name":"Алексей","Middlename":"Феникс +","CompanyName":"Феникс +"},{"Surname":"Куценко","Name":"Кирилл","Middlename":"Феникс-Презент","CompanyName":"Феникс-Презент"},{"Surname":"Скрипок","Name":"Дмитрий","Middlename":"Феникс +","CompanyName":"Феникс +"},null,null]
```

Вместо контакта в конце получил null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение. Переделал запрос таким образом:

```
var data  = from a in db.Contacts
join com in db.Companies on a.CompanyID equals com.CompanyID into ljoin1
from com in ljoin1.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
{
 Surname = a.Surname,
 Name = a.Name,
 Middlename = a != null ? a.Middlename : "Пусто",
 CompanyName = com != null ? com.CompanyName : "Пусто"
};
```